# How to resolve a JIRA bug in testlink

Tags: jira, testlink

While executing tests in testlink, Any failures are recorded in JIRA as Bugs and the bug ID is added in testLink using tool "Bug management".Once that JIRA bug is fixed and closed, how to mark the status as Closed / Resolved for the Bug in testlink.
Thanks.

Comment: Can I manually change the status of a JIRA BUG in testlink ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement jira listener in groovy which can call testlink api to resolve the testcase. 
https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Listeners
I did not see such method in the testlink java api but probably you can call a URL to resolve/close an issue.